# A Python gotcha: Stray comma at end of simple assignment

Tags: python

I just spent the better part of a day finding a bug caused by a stray comma at the end of an assignment statement. The difficulty in finding my bug was exacerbated by a third-party callback library that was trapping exceptions but it made me wonder why Python (2.x) doesn't raise a syntax error instead of creating a tuple.  Consider the following

```
>>> a = 1,
>>> a
(1,)
```

As you can see, the trailing comma creates a singleton tuple.  It's not a violation of the Python grammar (see http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-expression_list) but it can certainly lead to some unexpected results, e.g.

```
>>> a == 1,
(False,)
```

vs

```
>>> (1,) == a
True
```

Although I now understand what's going on, I'm puzzled about why Python permits this syntax instead of requiring explicit parentheses to create a tuple. **Is there some case where this behavior is necessary, or at least advantageous?**  I've been programming almost exclusively in Python for the past 7 years and I've never needed to create a singleton this way. Python is, in most respects, a wonderfully readable and explicit language. This particular "feature" seems, well, un-Pythonic.

Comment: Dunno about that last sentence... "Explicit is better than implicit."

Comment: I'd suggest getting in touch with the language maintainers, but here is not a great place for the discussion this question will likely spark.  The short answer is "that's how it's implemented" and for a longer explanation you should look to documentation or mailing lists, not SO.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, being explicit about creating a tuple would mean putting parentheses around it, right?

Comment: Because writing `return a, b, c` reads much nicer than `return (a, b, c)`. The operator precedence makes sense to me too, but it can be surprising.

Comment: @Voo even truer when assigning to those return values: a, b, c = f().  The lack of parentheses is more appropriate for this because you're not trying to make a tuple

Comment: @g.d.d.c:  I think this question was reasonably answerable.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the Guido van Rossum, creator of Python, [explaining](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2009_02_01_archive.html) how this bit of syntax came to be:

> One consequence of adding an array-like interface to tuples is that I
>   had to figure out some way to resolve the edge cases of tuples with
>   length 0 or 1. One of the rules I took from ABC was that every data
>   type, when printed or converted to a string, should be represented by
>   an expression that was a valid input to the language’s parser. So, it
>   followed that I needed to have notations for 0- and 1-length tuples.
>   At the same time I didn’t want to lose the distinction between a
>   one-tuple and a bare parenthesized expression, so I settled for an
>   ugly but pragmatic approach where a trailing comma would turn an
>   expression into a one-tuple and "()" would represent a zero-tuple.
>   It's worth nothing that parentheses aren’t normally required by
>   Python’s tuple syntax, except here--I felt representing the empty
>   tuple by “nothing” could too easily mask genuine typos.

See also this PythonInfo Wiki on [TupleSyntax](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax), especially "... it is the commas, not the parentheses, that define the tuple".

While this syntax isn't beautiful (Guido says ugly, but pragmatic), I don't think it is much of a gotcha.  The real gotcha was that your third party library was "trapping exceptions" thus hiding important information regarding your error.

Comment: Thanks, Steven.  I figured Guido must have had some reason for it. No disagreement about the third-party library, but still it's bothersome that something as hard to spot as stray comma in a large body of code should have cost me a day's effort.

Answer (score 2):

There's one example where it comes in handy, swapping two values. Certainly you could use explicit parentheses here but it looks better without them.

```
a, b = b, a
```

Comment: My question concerned only the singleton case. No disagreement about the usefulness with two or more elements in the tuple. I use it all time.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I don't have enough rep to comment, so this gets to be it's own answer.

There are two related but different things here -- tuple unpacking and just creating a tuple literal.

Tuple unpacking is found in Mark Ransom's answer.

Tuples though seem to be a stumbling block for people. They're not created with parentheses, parentheses are only used for disambiguation. A comma defines a tuple, so `a,` is a tuple with one element, because, well, that's what a tuple is, a thing with a comma :). (The caveat is that for the empty tuple, rather than `,` which looks ugly, we get stuck with `()`, which is perhaps the source of the difficulties people seem to have with this.)

Comment: +1.  Here is a basic restatement of your answer from the PythonInfo Wiki:  [TupleSyntax](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax).